# HREF Link ajax post request

Tags: php, ajax, post, request, href

To make shot, here is my problem. I have a script that sends Form POST request through ajax but my problem is I want to do it in A Href Tag. Below is my code for FORM POST Request:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $( ".searchForm" ).submit(function( event ) {
        event.preventDefault();

        var invoiceNo=$(".invoiceNo").val();
        var dataString = 'invoiceNo='+invoiceNo;

        $.ajax ({
            type: "POST",
            url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>/billing/test",
            data: dataString,
            cache: false,
            success: function(html) {
                $(".particularList_output").html(html);
            } 
        });

    });
});
</script>

<form action="/" class="searchForm">
<input type="hidden" class="invoiceNo" value="thisIsMyValue">
<button id="xSmall" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add Invoice</button>
</form>
```

Comment: so what's the problem? create link with all the data appended through query-string.

Comment: basically it is in Form Tag. I want it in A href link

Answer (score 1):

Do something like this:

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url();?>/billing/test" data-invoice="<?php echo $yourInvoiceNumber?>"> Add Invoice </a>

$('a').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var $this = $(this);

    $.ajax({
        url: $this.data('href'),
        type: 'POST',
        data: 'invoiceNo='+$this.data('invoice'),
        cache: false,
        success: function(html) {
            $(".particularList_output").html(html);
        } 
    });
});
```